# Name in alphabetic order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models in my project those are Supplier and Address models.

I am storing Supplier address information in address table like first_name,last_name..etc.

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now I want all suppliers in alphabetic order based on his name,Can any one knows?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But there we are getting order its own model. I want Suppliers based on his name in alphabetic order, here name column in address table not in suppliers table.?

Comment: You're going to have to be clearer about what you want to do, preferably with code.

Comment: Try `Supplier.includes(:address).order("addresses.name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Supplier.includes(:address).order("addresses.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`order` ActiveRecord method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) (which invokes the [`ORDER_BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) function in SQL):

```
@suppliers = Supplier.joins(:address).order(name: :desc)
```